# Installing Ubuntu on a laptop with an SSD

Tags: 12.04, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu on a laptop with an SSD. Will it be a problem in general to install Ubuntu on a laptop with an SSD instead of a laptop with an HDD? Which Linux kernel version is best for a laptop with an SSD?

Comment: Should work fine. Post if you have a problem or question.

Comment: Yep, works fine for my laptop.

Comment: Fair enough. Deleted.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no problem in installing Ubuntu on an SSD. In fact, if you have an SSD, it would be the most recommended place to install Ubuntu on. Thanks to the SSD, you will benefit from:

- Reduced booting time
- Faster app loading
- Fast Read/Write operations in general (Saving files, opening documents, music, photos...)
- No fragmentation (Although there was no fragmentation on HDD either)
- Longer life cycle (SSD tend to last longer than HDD)
- Everything will feel faster

Here is Ubuntu 13.10 on my SSD:

[image]

As you can see, is totally safe, secured, faster, stable and with a big jump in performance.